Show context menu addition only for object custom properties?
I am looking for a bpy.types.?????_MT_context_menu (or similar) so that I can insert an item Copy Color Property as new Driver for a script that will help me past the arduous task of adding a color type driver.   I'll develop an add-on like the following.  What would I replace the "???" test in the poll method, or other means of confining the added item only for the Custom Properties context?
class WM_OT_button_context_color_driver(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Copy Color as New Drive"""
    bl_idname = "wm.button_context_test"
    bl_label = "Copy Color as New Driver"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.active_object is not None) and (???)

    def execute(self, context):
        value = getattr(context, "button_pointer", None)
        if value is not None:
            dump(value, "button_pointer")

        value = getattr(context, "button_prop", None)
        if value is not None:
            dump(value, "button_prop")

        value = getattr(context, "button_operator", None)
        if value is not None:
            dump(value, "button_operator")

        return {'FINISHED'}

def draw_menu(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator(WM_OT_button_context_color_driver.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_button_context_color_driver)
    bpy.types.UI_MT_button_context_menu.append(draw_menu)


You don't put any menu type in the poll method. Poll method is for checking if certain conditions are met within the context to call the operator/menu. So like if you made a tool that only works with curve objects then you would put return context.object.type == "CURVE" or something.

I would recommend checking out the python templates and look at the UILayout ones, e.g. UIMenu, UIPanelSimple etc.
